# Why is our Android 2.2 application "incompatible" with Android 2.3.5

Tags: android

We are seeing a problem with our company's application that has me very confused about the Android compatibility model.

Our app supports Android 2.1 and later.  It is targeted for 2.2 and later.  Our application manifest expresses this as follows:

```
 <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" android:minSdkVersion="7"></uses-sdk>
```

One of our customers is having a problem running our app on a Sprint Motorola XT603, Android 2.3.5.

The app is visible to them in the Market (as expected),  yet when they try to run it, they get the following failure:

```
*'This app is incompatible with your Sprint Motorola XT603'.*
```

An interesting tidbit is that developer.android.com does not even list 2.3.5 as an Android version: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html.

From what I have read, I believe we are properly using the `<uses-sdk>` entry.  We have successfully installed and run our app on later Android version (HoneyComb/3.0).

Is anyone familiar with 2.3.5 and why this compatibility issue exists?

Comment: Maybe there are more messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android 2.3 is actually available in its 2.3.7 version.
But 2.3.5 to 2.3.7 are just bug fixes and application updates (for example : voice and video chat in Google Talk in 2.3.4), nothing new for developers...

It would have been a nonsense to change API level... 2.3.3+ is API level 10.

On the other hand, if the android market allows them to install the application, this application is assumed compatible: do your customers use a custom ROM ?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on 2.3.5.  That makes sense.

Comment: As for your question "do your customers use a custom ROM?", I'm new enough to Android that I dont quite know what that means.  Are you asking if Motorola has altered the version of Android that they ship on this particular phone?

Comment: Cell phone manufacturers make their own Rom based on Android: stock ROMs.

As Android is open source, anybody (skills requirements here) can play with it to make his own ROM. Custom ROMS are often faster, smoother, efficient and uses less memory, because (regarded as) useless applications are removed and kernel is optimized.

We could also talk about updates frequencies...

But sometimes an application doesn't work on a custom rom.
Because they are not done by Manufacturers, custom rom users can't (and shouldn't) blame developers, most of the time the problem is in the rom itself.